# Power BI create table relationship where field value contains string

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables on Power BI

Table 1: **Promoters**

| PromoterName | PromoterId |
| --- | --- |
| PromoterName1 | PromoterId1 |
| PromoterName | PromoterId2 |
| ... | ... |

Table 2: **Users**

| UserName | PromoterPath |
| --- | --- |
| UserName1 | promoterId1/promoterId2/promoterId3/... |
| UserName2 | promoterId1/promoterId2/promoterId3/... |
| ... | ... |

I would like to create a relationship between the two tables where Promoters[PromoterId] is related to Users[PromoterPath], so that if I select a promoter from the first tables I get all the Users who match that promoter in their paths.

Is it possibile to do?

Comment: there are some functions to handle strings, but I would recommend you work with an intermediary table; one row per username and a column for every promoter .. plain boolean cells .. if your number of promoters is exceedingly large your promoterpath column would/could explode anyway. Right!?!

Comment: @flowtron do you mean I need to create a table with the same amount of rows of Users and a number of columns equals to the number of rows of Promoters? And then, for each column I set True or False if the user has that promoter in its path? I don't think this would be very pratical for several reason: first because there are thousands of promoters and second because the number of promoters is not fixed but can increase.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by myself.
Here it is:

- I had to create a table where I put only two fields: user_id and promoter_path
- Then I use Power Query, click on the promoter_path column and select "split column by delimitator" and then I checked the option "Rows"
- Now I have the user_id which is repeated as many times as the number of the path items and all the promoter ids under promoter_path
- I renamed the column promoter_path into promoter_id

Now I have three tables:

- Promoters,
- Users,
- A third table I renamed users_promoters

The relationships must be

Users[id]->users_promoters[user_id]

Promoters[id]->users_promoters[promoter_id]